# How to get response back from Chrome Custom Tabs in react-native

Tags: react-native, chrome-custom-tabs

I want to get response from URL that is opened into chrome custom tab. actually i have some forms in external url that is submitted and return data array on success page. I want to get array into my app. when user click on button custom tab will open and submit required fields and goes into success page. I want to do custom tab will be close automatically and fetch array into app and want to create success page into app.

Comment: Hey did you find any way of doing this?